# How to clone a git repo using python?

Tags: python, git

I am looking for equivalent way to clone a repo in python

```
clone_start=`date +%s%N` && git clone --quiet ssh://$USER@$host:29418/git_performance_check >& /dev/null && c
lone_end=`date +%s%N`
        Time_clone=`echo "scale=2;($clone_end - $clone_start) / 1000000000" | bc`
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GitPyhton](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) lib

Clone from existing repositories or initialize new empty ones:

```
import git
host = 'github'
user = 'root'
git.Git().clone("ssh://{0}@{1}:29418/git_performance_check".format(user, host))
```

Comment: Will it do the quiet clone ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`GitPython`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/). Something like this:

```
    from git import Repo

    repo = Repo.init('/tmp/git_performance_check')
    repo.create_remote('origin', url='ssh://user@host:29418/git_performance_check')
    repo.remotes.origin.fetch()
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I generate ssh keys and clone git repo ? I couldn't find a way so far

Answer (score -3):

This is simple and straight forward method:

```
import os
os.chdir(path/where/you/need/to/store/your/project)
os.system("your/git/repository.git")
```

Comment: This answer does not perform a git clone. It's attempting to execute a command called "your/git/repository.git".

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `os.system("git clone your/git/repository.git")` assuming you have git installed.